# nHibernate stored procedure call

Tags: c#, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I'm quite new to nHibernate ORM. Could someone please help me to understand/resolve the scenario I've below?

I have a stored procedure called `getSummaryReport` which expects `@productID` as parameter. This stored procedure joins multiple tables and gives the summary data.

I need to load the data returned from the above stored procedure using nhibernate. Could someone please help me what how it's possible to call stored procedure via nHibernate?

Some of the questions running through my head right now is:

1. Do I need a mapping xml? If yes what goes on to the mapping xml as I understand there should be physical table for each property. In above case stored procedure is generating brand new object.
2. How do I call the above stored procedure from within C#?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, your mapping:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <sql-query name="SummaryReport">
    exec getSummaryReport  :productId
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and then use SetResultTransformer...

```
var results = Session
      .GetNamedQuery("SummaryReport")
      .SetInt32("productId", productId);
      .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(YOURCLASS)));
return results.List<YOURCLASS>();
```

and YOURCLASS is:-

```
public class YOURCLASS 
{
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Column1Returned { get; set; }
    public virtual int Column2Returned { get; set; }
            etc..
}
```

Make sure what ever is returned from your SP is defined in `YOURCLASS` remembering that your column names and property names have to match exactly as they are `CASE` sensitive.

Comment: Thank you @Rippo,does nHibernate mapping must have one unique ID? And also does YOURCLASS must have XML mapping?

Comment: Also, with nHibernate does all the XML *.nbh.xml must have corresponding physical table?

Comment: It is better if YOURCLASS have unqiue Id's but you don't need to have a mapped table for a corresponding XML file. The XML file above in my answer could just be called namedqueires.hbm.xml